# Force ftp to use USB hotspot interface

Tags: networking, server

Background: My home broadband speed is very slow, so I use my mobile hotspot (5G, unlimited data) to download large files. Currently, to store media on my NAS I download the file to my phone, then transfer to my NAS via USB.

I want to move to directly connecting my NAS to the media server via FTP and download files that way, but I need the NAS to use my mobile data hotspot whilst also staying on my home ethernet for access from local devices like my main desktop. When I tether my phone to my NAS, I see "usb0" in the list of network interfaces.

My question is, how do I force the `ftp` application to connect to the media server via the usb0 interface? I've seen threads like: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface

But when I follow this example, I don't get any connection with e.g. curl returning "Could not resolve host". I've got fairly basic level knowledge in UNIX. My local network is enp3s0 at 192.168.4.X.

Comment: Do you use a hostname for connecting or do you use an IP? If you use a hostname for connecting, instead use the IP of the host, which you wanna connect to. If you want to use a hostname, add that hostname and it's **fixed** IP to your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Hi @Faris. This is done by setting specific routes to the host or network you are trying to reach. You could specify different networks and then create the specific routes through them.

Comment: @paladin Are you talking about hostname vs IP for connecting to the NAS? I use my internal local IP to connect to the NAS, it's not accessible externally, and a hostname to connect to the FTP (which fails to connect when I follow the example steps on the link)

Comment: @jpbrain Interesting, I've got quite basic knowledge in Linux but I'll look into this thanks!

Comment: It seems you have problems with resolving hostnames. What I meant to say was: Don't use the hostname of that FTP server to connect to that FTP server, instead use its IP address.

Comment: @paladin Makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is a more detailed answer.
On any unix/linux machine you setup every interface with at least 3 parameters:

> IP, Default Gateway/Route and Netmask
> IP: is the actual direction for your inteface
> Gateway: is the primary contact to reach other networks
> Netmask: Would be a definition of what actually is your local network

then there is the DNS that it is only needed when you want to resolve out of the network host/IPs. If you configure names in the /etc/hosts then you know the translation between the name and the local IPs.

Now. if you have more than one way to reach the network you could use something like:

> ROUTE add [destination] [MASK netmask] [gateway] [METRIC metric] [IF interface]

here you tell the server to use [gateway] to reach [destination] on a specific [IF interface]
using this you bind the routes by IP/Interface and it is not related to the program you are using.

Please, go ahead and google the specifics and try it.

Good luck.

Comment: I got it working, thanks for the explanation!